# Why arr is same to *arr in this program?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr[][2] = {1,2,3,4};
    printf("0x%p\n", arr);
    printf("0x%p\n", *arr);
    return 0;
}
```

[Code and running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPJB7.png)

Answer (score 9):

Arrays decays to *pointers to their first element*.

So when you print `arr` it's really `&arr[0]`.

And when you print `*arr` it's really `&arr[0][0]`.

And both start at the same location.

It's easy to see if we look at how the arrays would be in memory:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | arr[1][0] | arr[1][1] |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
^
|
&arr[0][0]
|
&arr[0]
|
&arr
```

The big difference between the different pointers is not their location, it's their *type*: `&arr[0][0]` is of type `int *`; `&arr[0]` is of type `int (*)[2]`; And `&arr` is of type `int (*)[2][2]`.

---

It also helps when dealing with these things to know that for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`.

Armed with that knowledge, if we take e.g. `&arr[0]` it is equal to `&(*(arr + 0))`. Which is equal to `&(*arr)` which is equal to `arr` (because the address-of operator `&` and dereference operator `*` cancel each other out).

---

As mentioned `arr[0]` is also equal to `0[arr]`. This also comes from the `arr[i]` and `*(arr + i)` equivalence.

Because of the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of addition, the expression `*(arr + i)` is equal to `*(i + arr)`, which then leads to the odd `i[arr]` syntax.

This is a curiosity, that should not be done in "real" code.

Comment: Excellent, this should be the new canonical duplicate for these kinds of questions :D

Comment: ... and `arr[0]` is the same as `0[arr]` (try it).

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an array, so when you use it in an expression it evaluates to a pointer to the first element.

Similarly, `*arr` is also an array, so it is also converted to a pointer to the first element.

The values are the same because an array's address is the same as the address of its first element, although the *types* are different.